# NFS shared folder ownership does not change in guest OS in Vagrant

Tags: nfs, vagrant, shared-folders

I have the following Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.nfs.map_uid = 33
config.nfs.map_gid = 33

config.vm.synced_folder "/home/test", "/home/test", type: "nfs"
...
```

After `vagrant up` `/home/test` folder successfully mounted but uid=1000 and gid=1000 (1000 - owner of this folder on host), not 33. In host's `/etc/exports` everything looks good to me:

```
"/home/test" 10.0.0.2(rw,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=33,anongid=33,fsid=2395053692)
```

**Vagrant version:** 1.6.5

**Host OS:** Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

**Guest OS:** Debian 6.0.9

UPD. Submitted issue https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer of Vagrant has answered the [question on Github](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4816#issuecomment-120051938):

> This is correct. it doesn't change the owner, it just changes the user
>   that files are read/written as when they are accessed on the guest.
>   You won't see any visible change in the guest.